# How to deal: qsqltablemodel does not load view

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt, uitableview, qsqltablemodel

I have a pretty simple system of 2 views in SQLite DB and 2 tableViews in Desktop Qt Widget Application:

1. First view is 'seller_view' and it is just printed in App's tableView correctly via QSqlTableModel.
2. Second is 'customer_view' (setup is the same as above) and it does not print any data, but shows model's headers, that was set up in constructor.

So, we got a strange situation when:

**SQL View data in SQLiteStudio (view 'customer_view')**
[image]

**Model setup**

```
    // model for tableView
    model = new QSqlTableModel();
    model->setTable("customer_view");
    model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
    updateView();
    model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("ID"));
    model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Ім'я")); // only organizations will have ipn
    model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, tr("К-сть авто"));
    model->setHeaderData(3, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Адреса"));
    model->setHeaderData(4, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Номер"));
    model->setHeaderData(5, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Ел.пошта"));
    model->setHeaderData(6, Qt::Horizontal, tr("ІБАН"));
    model->setHeaderData(7, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Банк"));
    model->setHeaderData(8, Qt::Horizontal, tr("ЄДРПОУ"));
    model->setHeaderData(9, Qt::Horizontal, tr("ІПН"));

    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    ui->tableView->setColumnHidden(ID_COLUMN_INDEX, true); // hide ID
    ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);

    connect(model, &QSqlTableModel::dataChanged, this, &Customers::handleDataChange);
```

**QTableView in app 'customer_view'**
[image]

**I have some conclusions:**

1. QSqlTableModel works fine, because tables(views) names (i checked 10 times) are correct, and it displays columns names correctly, so i can say, that tableView model setup was OK.
2. SQL View is correct because SQLiteStudio shows the data it should. Again, names of views are correct
3. If i replace the working model's QSqlTableModel::setTable('seller_view') with 'customer_view', it does not show data, as expected. So, i'm almost sure that the problem is in SQL database.

P.S.: I also tried to change view name 'customer_view' -> 'cus'. Nothing changed

P.S.S.: I set up database in correct way, because changing 'seller' data in SQLiteStudio leads to changing 'seller_view' in App. So, the problem is 100% with the 'customer_view', and i am confused. Maybe query breaks my database?

```
SELECT customer.id,
           customer.name,
           COUNT(car.id),
           customer.address,
           customer.number,
           customer.email,
           customer.iban,
           customer.bank,
           customer.edrpoy,
           customer.ipn
      FROM customer
           LEFT JOIN
           car ON customer.id = car.customer_id
     GROUP BY customer.id
```

P.S.S.S:

```
void Customers::updateView()
{
    model->select();
}
```

**seller_view sql**

```
SELECT seller.id,
           seller.name,
           seller.address,
           seller.number,
           seller.iban,
           seller.bank,
           seller.edrpoy,
           seller.ipn
      FROM seller
```

P.S.S.S.S (everything from this stuff is working right and updates the table and the view in SQLiteStudio, but is not shown by model as seller_view does):

```
void Customers::on_btn_add_clicked()
{
    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.exec("INSERT INTO customer(name) VALUES(NULL)");

    updateView();
}

void Customers::on_btn_del_clicked()
{
    const auto selected_indexes = ui->tableView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
    QSqlQuery qry;
    if (!selected_indexes.isEmpty())
    {
        qry.exec("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
        qry.exec("DELETE FROM customer WHERE id=" + selected_indexes.at(0).siblingAtColumn(ID_COLUMN_INDEX)
                 .data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString()
                 );
    }

    updateView();
}

void Customers::handleDataChange(const QModelIndex &topLeft, const QModelIndex &)
{
    const QVector<int> notEditableColumns = {
        2 /* Cars count is NOT EDITABLE */
    };
    const int column = topLeft.column();
    const QString data = topLeft.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
    const QString customer_id = topLeft.siblingAtColumn(ID_COLUMN_INDEX).data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();

    if (!notEditableColumns.contains(column)) {
        switch (column) {
        case 1: {
            handleSimpleCellChange("name", data, customer_id);
        } break;
        case 3: {
            handleSimpleCellChange("address", data, customer_id);
        } break;
        case 4: {
            handleSimpleCellChange("number", data, customer_id);
        } break;
        case 5: {
            handleSimpleCellChange("email", data, customer_id);
        } break;
        case 6: {
            handleSimpleCellChange("iban", data, customer_id);
        } break;
        case 7: {
            handleSimpleCellChange("bank", data, customer_id);
        } break;
        case 8: {
            handleSimpleCellChange("edrpoy", data, customer_id);
        } break;
        case 9: {
            handleSimpleCellChange("ipn", data, customer_id);
        } break;
        }
    }

    updateView();
}

void Customers::handleSimpleCellChange(const QString &columnName, const QString &data, const QString &customer_id)
{
    QSqlQuery qry;
    const QString query_str = "UPDATE customer SET %1=%2 WHERE id=%3";
    qry.exec(query_str.arg(columnName, data, customer_id));
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `updateView` function code? And, btw, are you updating the view before setting a model to it?

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o Thank you for your reply. UpdateView is just a public slot for model->select()

Comment: Ok. Can you show SQL for seller_view?

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o yeah

Comment: Well, we have a clue now :) Are you willing to edit customer_view data from the view? (I guess you're not)

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o Yeah, im ready :3 Do u see the connect under QSqlTableView setup in constructor? It handles changes and uses QSqlQuery to UPDATE the data in table 'customer' columns. Anyway, i guess it's not the matter why data is not shown

Comment: We'll see if it matters :). Did you use CREATE VIEW in sqlite for any of them?

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o No, i'm not. Let me show you all the queries

Comment: and the `handleDataChange` function, please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not using the model to directly write to the underlying tables, I would give `QSqlQueryModel` a try: just use it instead of `QSqlTableModel`, and replace your

```
model->select();
```

with

```
model.setQuery("select * from customer_view");
```

Since this model is read only, you may want to drop the model/view strategy altogether, and fall back to using a QSqlQuery and populating a QTableWidget with its result. This method should be faster than using a subclassed model that provides data/setData implementations, also considering you already wrote code to edit the db on a single-cell data change basis.

Comment: Huh.. It works!! Amazing! But there is a problem. It's not editable... Can you tell me, please, is there a way to make it editable without inheriting setData?

Comment: Sorry @SageCat since you're joining and using a GROUP BY clause, using writable models isn't really handy at all ...

Comment: Yeah, a bit. But it somehow works fine with 'seller_view' table and i feel that the task is almost done :)
I dont want to stop at this point. Huh...